# MVC modelMetadata splitting properties to smaller subset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ORDERMetadata with 10 properties, but I only want to pass a model with only 5 of the properties to my view1, but have the rest other 5 properties to View2.  Is there a way to create smaller models within ORDERMetadata that will allow me to only grab the properties I want by setting something in ORDERMetadata class?

Like can I do this for my views?

```
@using MVC.models.OrderMetadata<View1Model?>

@using MVC.models.OrderMetadata<View2Model?>
```

My OrderModel.cs

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(ORDERMetadata))]
    public partial class ORDER
    {
       // Note this class has nothing in it.  It's just here to add the class-level attribute.

    }

    public class ORDERMetadata
    {

        // <--- Model 1 Begin, for View1

        [Required]
        public int 1 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public bool 2 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public bool 3 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public bool 4 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public bool 5 { get; set; }

        // <--- Model 1 End


        //<---- Model 2, for View2

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public System.DateTime 6 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public string 7 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public string 8 { get; set; }        

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public string 9 { get; set; }        

        [Display(Name = "")]
        public string 10 { get; set; }  

        //<---- Model 2 end 


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some strange facts in this whole thing...

> I have a ORDERMetadata with 10 properties, but I only want to pass a model with only 5 of the properties to my view1, but have the rest other 5 properties to View2. Is there a way to create smaller models within ORDERMetadata that will allow me to only grab the properties I want by setting something in ORDERMetadata class

What? First, normally you'll render only one View, right? So why do you want to split your object and use 2 views at once? I would need a more detailed explanation to understand your need.

> Like can I do this for my views?
>   @using MVC.models.OrderMetadata< View1Model?> 
>   @using MVC.models.OrderMetadata< View2Model?>

No. First, I guess that you are trying to make a strongtyped View. That's the right thing to do, but you're doing this wrong. `@using` means that you are creating an alias for a namespace or to import types defined in other namespaces. There is nothing to do with the model to your View.

To make a Strongtyped View Your would be something like this:

`MyNamespace.ViewModels.MyViewModel`

 Is important to remember that you can have only on Model/ViewModel per View, so you can't (and don't even should) use two ViewModels in one View.

Also, properties with name of numbers is a extremely anti-pattern, so please, don't do it. If it's someway used in a dynamic way, you should create a collection and iterate over it.

About the MetadataType Attribute it's not meant to be used like you are doing. Take a look: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/why-it-is-wrong-to-use-the-asp-net-mvc-metadatatype-attribute

Now, what about doing this structure:

C#:

```
public class OrdersVM
{
        public FirstDisplayVM FirstDisplay { get; set; }
        public SecondDisplayVM SecondDisplay { get; set; }


        public class FirstDisplayVM
        {
            public int Prop1 { get; set; }
            public List<bool> MyBooleanValues { get; set; }
        }

        public class SecondDisplayVM
        {
            public int Prop1 { get; set; }
            public List<string> MyStringValues { get; set; }
        }
}
```

View:

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.ViewModels.OrderVM
```

That is just a scratch. You don't really make your needs clear nor what is exactly this properties for, but is somewhat a pattern to follow.

Also a universal programming advice: You really should use the most semantically names you can imagine for every your classes, properties, namespaces, attributes, EVERYTHING! Then, once you read the name of your property after some time, or in another class/view, you knows exactly why it's for, and will not need to guessing/riddling "what the hell is this property/class/etc...".

If you are new to ASP.Net MVC, you should learn about ViewModels as much as you can before you do anything. A structure created without knowing the right patterns and how to do it properly will become a nightmare to maintain, when programming is a dream.

A ViewModel introduction:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3
http://sampathloku.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html
http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm

Data Anotattions (General > Display / DataType / Range / etc...):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Data Anotattions (Validation):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28VS.100%29.aspx
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

Comment: With your example, can I add data notations to it like  [Required], [Display(Name = "")?

Comment: Undoubtedly! They also are bind to the View, and have a automatic integration with jQuery Validator. Also you can set the Display Attribute and use the Razor Helper `Html.DisplayFor()` to create the proper html for you. This is the charm of ViewModels. They have all this information organized and concise. Take a look in the ViewModel introduction. There is a plenty information about using the DataAnnotation attribute to properly specify behaviors for your properties.

Comment: OK. great!  I do not see why I would need ModelMetaData then, since I just used to set data notation attributes.

Comment: Exactly. Indeed, the data annotation may reside in your ViewModel. I really can't see any situation where you should separate the DataAnnotation from the properties you want to pass for a View (your ViewModel).

Comment: I made a update, including more information about DataAnnotation for specify validation rules, specify how the data is displayed, and set relationships between classes.